# Issue Decrypting File with OpenSSL: "hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length"

Tags: bash, terminal, passwords, openssl, decryption

I'm encountering an issue while trying to decrypt a file using Open SSL. I have a file named `fc382Crypto.bin` provided by my instructor, and I need to decrypt it using the blowfish algorithm with CBC mode.

Here's the command I'm using to decrypt the file:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -in fc382Crypto.bin -out decrypted_output.txt -K 112233445566778899 -iv 0000000000000000
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
bad decrypt
```

I've tried adjusting the command by adding the `-nopad` option, but the issue persists. I've also verified the integrity of the `fc382Crypto.bin` file to ensure it hasn't been corrupted.

The encryption settings provided by my instructor are as follows:

```
Algorithm: Blowfish
Mode: CBC
Key: 112233445566778899
IV: 0
```

I'm not sure why I'm encountering this error or how to resolve it. Can someone please provide guidance on how to decrypt this file correctly using OpenSSL?

[image]

Comment: Please add fc382Crypto.bin to your question.

Comment: **aes-128-cbc is NOT blowfish**. Although the blowfish algorithm and the libcrypto implementation support variable keysize, openssl _commandline_ only supports 128-bit (16-byte or 32-hexit) and you don't have such a key -- unless the instructor actually used openssl commandline (incorrectly) with the short key and got the padding but withheld this info from you.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I removed the image with the instructions due to privacy concern, but it can [still be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP8Ip.jpg).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - The key is fine you just have to pad it with zeros, this is obviously homework, not sure what the privacy concerns are though.

Comment: @Ramhound The “Property of…” watermark in the picture.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I assumed it was the professor not the student cheating on the assignment. If there is a real privacy problem the the image should be redacted. Just editing it out doesn’t really do anything

Comment: @Ramhound True. Re-adding the image. Could just be the professor’s name.

Comment: @Ramhound: unless the encryption was done with openssl commandline, which is not said, there's no reason the key needs to be padded at all.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - I strongly disagree. The instructions for the assignment, said it was encrypted with a openssl command line, and the warning is being thrown which suggests the key wasn't padded.  I also have strong negative feelings about helping somebody cheat.  Since the author has provided zero feedback, I am inclined to delete my answer, allowing this question caused by zero research on the author's part to be thrown into the void.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why I'm encountering this error or how to resolve it.

You’re using a 128-bit encryption algorithm. So your encryption key and Initialization Vector (IV) need to be 128-bits long.

Key: **0x00000000000000112233445566778899**

IV:  **0x00000000000000000000000000000000**

> An encryption method of AES-128 signals that Media Segments are completely encrypted using the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) [AES_128] with a 128-bit key, Cipher Block Chaining (CBC), and Public-Key Cryptography Standards #7 (PKCS7) padding [RFC5652]. CBC is restarted on each segment boundary, using either the Initialization Vector (IV) attribute value or the Media Sequence Number as the IV; see Section 5.2.
>
> IV
>
> The value is a hexadecimal-sequence that specifies a 128-bit
> unsigned integer Initialization Vector to be used with the key.
> Use of the IV attribute REQUIRES a compatibility version number of
> 2 or greater.  See Section 5.2 for when the IV attribute is used.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.2.4